# How to get particular field from a json object returned by # facebook graph url lookup using ajax

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a particular field values from a json object returned facebook graph api using javascript ajax call.

I am trying following code to get the cover field from json object but its not accessible .
**for referenced http://jsfiddle.net/GD4PC/**
her is the code

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           var ur="https://facebook.com/344128252278047";
           var res= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           console.log(res);
           document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=res.cover;

       }
       else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400')
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
       }
```

Comment: what content `res` has post that as well?

Comment: you can refer to http://jsfiddle.net/GD4PC/  in console for content.

Comment: you want this as innerHTML of div `{"cover_id":779886642035537,"offset_x":0,"offset_y":0,"source":"https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/q73/s720x720/10168003_779886642035537_6276624582415985745_n.jpg"}`

Comment: @Mritunjay I have to access **source** to fetch image url . but to access that first I have to get cover object then onnly i can reach to source .Correct me if i am wrong.So query would be like **re.cover.source**

Comment: I've added an answer for what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look at your content of `res` you will know the `cover` field is not directly accessible.

To access `cover` try this.

```
res[ur].cover
```

To access that `source` which you've mentioned in comment you should say

```
res[ur].cover.source
```

Because your object has a field `"https://facebook.com/344128252278047"` which is same as `ur`. In that field there is a field `cover`.

Comment: thanks for your help. but to access source the query would be like     `res[ur].cover[source]` as source is a filed in object cover.

Comment: @user3421202 I tried with `res[ur].cover[source]` but it didn't worked, are you sure?

Comment: @user3421202 not getting any fiddle.

Comment: @user3421202 I think you are little confused you are saying `cover["source"]` not cover[source]. see properly. and `cover["source"]` and `cover.source` are same.

Comment: Ok yeah,Sorry for that ,These are two different ways to access a property of an object .

Comment: ya basically we go for `object[key]` when key is a variable.